# Putting two links in the same box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a project where we aren't allowed to touch the html, but instead, design a CSS page with flex box and whatnot to alter the design. The html code has links to other CSS page designs for this project with the design type, and the designer name. I want to put these two links in the same circle box. If you run the code, you'll see the design name and the designer name are in the same circle - how do I go about putting them in the same circle? I believe theres a way to without altering the html since the design is in "class="design-name" and the designer is in "class="designer-name". In the code, it looks like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-family: 'Prata', serif;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-family: 'Prata', serif;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
}

.design-name {
  color: black;
}

.designer-name {
  color: black;
}

.designer-name li a {
  background: green;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 115px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-flex;
}

li a {
  background: red;
  box-shadow: black;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 115px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
}

li a:hover {
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display|Prata" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CSS Zen Garden: The Beauty of CSS Design</title>
  <link href="zengarden.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="Dave Shea">
  <meta name="description" content="A demonstration of what can be accomplished visually through CSS-based design.">
  <meta name="robots" content="all">


  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="script/html5shiv.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
</head>

<body id="css-zen-garden">
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <aside class="sidebar" role="complementary">
      <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="design-selection" id="design-selection">
          <h3 class="select">Select a Design:</h3>
          <nav role="navigation">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/221/" class="design-name">Mid Century Modern</a> by <a href="http://andrewlohman.com/" class="designer-name">Andrew Lohman</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/220/" class="design-name">Garments</a> by <a href="http://danielmall.com/" class="designer-name">Dan Mall</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/219/" class="design-name">Steel</a> by <a href="http://steffen-knoeller.de" class="designer-name">Steffen Knoeller</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/218/" class="design-name">Apothecary</a> by <a href="http://trentwalton.com" class="designer-name">Trent Walton</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/217/" class="design-name">Screen Filler</a> by <a href="http://elliotjaystocks.com/" class="designer-name">Elliot Jay Stocks</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/216/" class="design-name">Fountain Kiss</a> by <a href="http://jeremycarlson.com" class="designer-name">Jeremy Carlson</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/215/" class="design-name">A Robot Named Jimmy</a> by <a href="http://meltmedia.com/" class="designer-name">meltmedia</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/214/" class="design-name">Verde Moderna</a> by <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/" class="designer-name">Dave Shea</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Any guidance would be awesome!

Desired outcome, with both design name and designer being clickable links:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an image of what this is supposed to look like? Do you mean that the `li` should be a circle holding all the links?

Comment: I added an image of what my desired outcome is!

Comment: Where's that image?

Comment: Just added, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the css of `<a>` to the `<li>`...

Also apply `display:flex` to the `ul` and `li` to adjust the alignment of inner items

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav ul li {
  background: red;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body id="css-zen-garden">
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <aside class="sidebar" role="complementary">
      <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="design-selection" id="design-selection">
          <h3 class="select">Select a Design:</h3>
          <nav role="navigation">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/221/" class="design-name">Mid Century Modern</a> by <a href="http://andrewlohman.com/" class="designer-name">Andrew Lohman</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/220/" class="design-name">Garments</a> by <a href="http://danielmall.com/" class="designer-name">Dan Mall</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/219/" class="design-name">Steel</a> by <a href="http://steffen-knoeller.de" class="designer-name">Steffen Knoeller</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/218/" class="design-name">Apothecary</a> by <a href="http://trentwalton.com" class="designer-name">Trent Walton</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/217/" class="design-name">Screen Filler</a> by <a href="http://elliotjaystocks.com/" class="designer-name">Elliot Jay Stocks</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/216/" class="design-name">Fountain Kiss</a> by <a href="http://jeremycarlson.com" class="designer-name">Jeremy Carlson</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/215/" class="design-name">A Robot Named Jimmy</a> by <a href="http://meltmedia.com/" class="designer-name">meltmedia</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/214/" class="design-name">Verde Moderna</a> by <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/" class="designer-name">Dave Shea</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </aside>
  </div>
</body>
```